# CefSharp application launched with Shadow Copy

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

I created a Windows Forms application that uses a ChromiumBrowser. The application is composed by the follow components:

- Main application
- Web browser library
- Launcher application

When I launch my application normally, the web browser works correctly. If I launch my application from a launcher, the web browser doesn't work. It tolds me the follow error:

> Unhandled exception of 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Unknown module.
>
> Cannot load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=57.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or a relative dependency.
>
> Unable to found the specified file.

I need to use the launcher not only for updates, but since the application is distributed on network, sometimes there are problems to access files on the server.

The problem is not relative only to my app. I created a test solution that I posted below and I have had the same issue.

### Notes on the project

- Cefsharp runtime is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\CEFRuntime\x64 and C:\Program Files (x86)\CEFRuntime\x86. (I created an installer that copy the runtime files in this position). Runtime is based on the NuGet package.
- All executables are compiled in AnyCpu (AnyCpu support)

Cefsharp version 57 (Cef redist 3.2987.1601)

### Runtime content

x64 folder

- cef.pak
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.pdb
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.pdb
- CefSharp.Core.dll
- CefSharp.Core.pdb
- CefSharp.Core.xml
- CefSharp.dll
- CefSharp.pdb
- CefSharp.WinForms.dll
- CefSharp.WinForms.pdb
- CefSharp.WinForms.XML
- CefSharp.XML
- cef_100_percent.pak
- cef_200_percent.pak
- cef_extensions.pak
- chrome_elf.dll
- d3dcompiler_47.dll
- devtools_resources.pak
- icudtl.dat
- libcef.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- natives_blob.bin
- snapshot_blob.bin
- widevinecdmadapter.dll
- locales folder (with all .paks)

x86 folder

- cef.pak
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.pdb
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.pdb
- CefSharp.Core.dll
- CefSharp.Core.pdb
- CefSharp.Core.xml
- CefSharp.dll
- CefSharp.pdb
- CefSharp.WinForms.dll
- CefSharp.WinForms.pdb
- CefSharp.WinForms.XML
- CefSharp.XML
- cef_100_percent.pak
- cef_200_percent.pak
- cef_extensions.pak
- chrome_elf.dll
- d3dcompiler_47.dll
- devtools_resources.pak
- icudtl.dat
- libcef.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- natives_blob.bin
- snapshot_blob.bin
- widevinecdmadapter.dll
- locales folder (with all .paks)

I post the test solution that gives me the same error.

### Test Solution

The test solution is composed by three projects:

- StackOverflowIssueLauncher
- StackOverflowIssue (reference to WebBrowser)
- WebBrowser (dll library that contains the webbrowser)

The code is shown below:

#### Project StackOverflowIssueLauncher

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowIssueLauncher {

    /// <summary>
    /// Launcher program
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Program {

        /// <summary>
        /// Launcher body
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread, LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost)]
        private static void Main() {

            //Initialize path of application
            string startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string cachePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Program-" + Guid.NewGuid());
            string assemblyPath = CanonicalizePathCombine(startupPath, @"..\..\..\StackOverflowIssue\bin\Debug\");
            string executablePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "StackOverflowIssue.exe");
            string configFile = executablePath + ".config";

            //Start App Domain
            try {
                var setup = new AppDomainSetup() {
                    ApplicationName = "StackOverflowIssue",
                    ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
                    ShadowCopyDirectories = assemblyPath,
                    CachePath = cachePath,
                    ConfigurationFile = configFile
                };

                var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("StackOverflowIssue", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);
                domain.ExecuteAssembly(executablePath);
                AppDomain.Unload(domain);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            //Empty cache path
            try {
                Directory.Delete(cachePath, true);
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                //DO NOTHING
            }
        }

        private static string CanonicalizePathCombine(string sourcePath, string destPath) {
            string resultPath = Path.Combine(sourcePath, destPath);
            var sb = new StringBuilder(Math.Max(260, 2 * resultPath.Length));
            PathCanonicalize(sb, resultPath);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool PathCanonicalize([Out] StringBuilder sb, string src);
    }
}
```

---

#### Project StackOverflowIssue

WebControlForm.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebBrowser;

namespace StackOverflowIssue {

    /// <summary>
    /// Form that contains the webbrowser control
    /// </summary>
    public class WebControlForm : Form {

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new web control form
        /// </summary>
        public WebControlForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Controls.Add(new CefControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // WebControlForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(529, 261);
            this.Name = "WebControlForm";
            this.Text = "WebControlForm";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

MainForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowIssue {

    /// <summary>
    /// Main application form
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form {

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the main form
        /// </summary>
        public MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Show a new Web Control form
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Object that raised the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
        private void ShowBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var wcf = new WebControlForm();
            wcf.Show(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Variabile di progettazione necessaria.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Pulire le risorse in uso.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">ha valore true se le risorse gestite devono essere eliminate, false in caso contrario.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Codice generato da Progettazione Windows Form

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo necessario per il supporto della finestra di progettazione. Non modificare
        /// il contenuto del metodo con l'editor di codice.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.ShowBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // ShowBtn
            // 
            this.ShowBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.ShowBtn.Name = "ShowBtn";
            this.ShowBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(134, 40);
            this.ShowBtn.TabIndex = 0;
            this.ShowBtn.Text = "Show web browser";
            this.ShowBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.ShowBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ShowBtn_Click);
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ShowBtn);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.Text = "Main form";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button ShowBtn;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebBrowser;

namespace StackOverflowIssue {

    /// <summary>
    /// Main application program
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Program {

        /// <summary>
        /// Main application program.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread] private static void Main() {
            WebBrowserInitializer.Initialize();
            Debug.Print("Application started");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="cef.redist.x64" version="3.2987.1601" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="cef.redist.x86" version="3.2987.1601" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="CefSharp.Common" version="57.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="CefSharp.WinForms" version="57.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

---

#### Project WebBrowser

CefControl.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WebBrowser {

    /// <summary>
    /// WebBrowser control
    /// </summary>
    public class CefControl: UserControl {

        public CefControl() {
            CefInitializer.Initialize();

            InitializeComponent();
            var cr = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
            cr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Controls.Add(cr);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Variabile di progettazione necessaria.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Pulire le risorse in uso.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">ha valore true se le risorse gestite devono essere eliminate, false in caso contrario.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Codice generato da Progettazione componenti

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo necessario per il supporto della finestra di progettazione. Non modificare 
        /// il contenuto del metodo con l'editor di codice.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

CefInitializer.cs

```
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowser {

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that contains the base methods for CEF initializations
    /// </summary>
    public static class CefInitializer {

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize properties
        /// </summary>
        static CefInitializer() {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "SOIssue", "Cache");
            LogFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "SOIssue", "Logs");
            UserDataPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "SOIssue", "Data");

            if (!Directory.Exists(CachePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(CachePath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(LogFile))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(LogFile);
            if (!Directory.Exists(UserDataPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(UserDataPath);

            //Complete the files combine
            LogFile = Path.Combine(LogFile, "WebBrowser.log");

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += (sender, args) => Shutdown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shutdown all CEF instances
        /// </summary>
        internal static void Shutdown() {
            using (var syncObj = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()) {
                syncObj.Send(o => {
                    if (Cef.IsInitialized)
                        Cef.Shutdown();
                }, new object());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize CEF libraries
        /// </summary>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] internal static void Initialize() {
            if (Cef.IsInitialized)
                return;

            //Get proxy properties
            WebProxy proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy as WebProxy;
            string cefPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Cef)).Location);
            Debug.Print($"CEF Library Path: {cefPath}");
            Debug.Assert(cefPath != null, nameof(cefPath) + " != null");

            var settings = new CefSettings() {
                BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(cefPath, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"),
                LocalesDirPath = Path.Combine(cefPath, "locales"),
                ResourcesDirPath = cefPath,
                Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name,
                CachePath = CachePath,
                LogFile = LogFile,
                UserDataPath = UserDataPath
            };

            if (proxy == null || proxy.Address.AbsoluteUri != string.Empty)
                settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server", string.Empty);

            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }

        internal static readonly string CachePath;
        internal static readonly string LogFile;
        internal static readonly string UserDataPath;
    }
}
```

WebBrowserInitializer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WebBrowser {

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that contains the assembly resolve functions
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebBrowserInitializer {
        private static readonly object _initializer = new object();
        private static bool _initialized;

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the WebBrowser is initialized
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsInitialized {
            get {
                lock (_initializer)
                    return _initialized;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the current assembly
        /// </summary>
        public static void Initialize() {
            lock (_initializer) {
                if (!_initialized) {
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CefSharp_AssemblyResolve;
                    _initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Try to resolve the assembly
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Object that has raised the event</param>
        /// <param name="args">Event raised</param>
        /// <returns>Assembly loaded</returns>
        private static Assembly CefSharp_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
            Debug.Print($"Library: {args.Name}");

            if (!args.Name.StartsWith("CefSharp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return null;

            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(new[] {','}, 2)[0] + ".dll";

            foreach (var path in GetAssemblyPaths()) {
                string checkPath = Path.Combine(path, assemblyName);

                if (File.Exists(checkPath)) {
                    Debug.Print($"Relative path FOUND for {args.Name} in {checkPath}");
                    return Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(checkPath);
                }

                Debug.Write($"Relative path not found for {args.Name} in {checkPath}");
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all possible assembly paths
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of possible assembly paths</returns>
        private static IEnumerable<string> GetAssemblyPaths() {
            string pathPrefix = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86";

            if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CEFRuntime\" + pathPrefix))
                yield return @"C:\Program Files (x86)\CEFRuntime\" + pathPrefix;
            
            yield return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, pathPrefix);
            yield return Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, pathPrefix);

            Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CefInitializer));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAssembly.Location))
                yield return Path.Combine(currentAssembly.Location, pathPrefix);
        }
    }
}
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="cef.redist.x64" version="3.2987.1601" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="cef.redist.x86" version="3.2987.1601" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="CefSharp.Common" version="57.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="CefSharp.WinForms" version="57.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at CefSharp General Usage (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitation), I noticed a line that explains that CefSharp works **only** on default AppDomain. I have looked at the project https://github.com/stever/AppHostCefSharp and I found a solution.

I need to run the WebBrowser on a Default AppDomain (I forked and edited RedGate.AppHost repository. See below for why i did it.). To allow communications between controls I implements two NamedPipes services, one on the main form, another on the created object.

I posted the complete solution (https://github.com/rupertsciamenna89/cefsharp-remoting) so the source code will be simplier to see. And it can be improved or fixed (like my english :))

I renamed the original projects to better names.

The solution is composed of 4 projects:

- MainApplication [old StackOverflowIssue] (base application that I have to launch with ShadowCopy)
- MainApplication.Launcher [old StackOverflowIssue.Launcher] (application launcher)
- MainApplication.WebBrowser [old WebBrowser] (winforms controls library that contains the WebBrowser)
- MainApplication.Interfaces (interfaces that must be implemented for the operations)

### MainApplication.Interfaces

This project contains the interfaces that must be implemented by the client and the server. It contains five files:

- **IFormService** is the interface that allows to create the control throught the RedGate.AppHost. It contains two Guids that identifies the unique names for Control/Server named pipes.
- **IAppClient** is the client interface that will be implemented into the Control library to perform remote calls on the Application.
- **IAppServer** is the server interface that will be implemented into the Application to accept remote calls from the Control library.
- **IWebBrowserClient** is the client interface that will be implemented into Application to perform remote calls on the Control library.
- **IWebBrowserServer** is the server interface that will be implemented into the Control libray to accept remote calls from the Application.

### MainApplication.WebBrowser

This project implements the OutOfProcessEntryPoint interface that initializes the Control WCF Service. It contains the implementation of the Server interface and allows the remote client show the folder and retrieve the returned result.

### MainApplication

I edited the Program.Main accepting the binaries path. I save this argument into a static variable that I'll use to crate the child process handle. The function that creates the process handle is this:

```
public static IChildProcessHandle CreateChildProcessHandle() {
    string assemblyPath = _sourcePath ?? Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WebBrowserInitializer)).Location);
    Debug.Assert(assemblyPath != null, "assemblyPath != null");
    var al = new ChildProcessFactory() { ClientExecutablePath = _sourcePath };
    return al.Create(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "MainApplication.WebBrowser.dll"), false, Environment.Is64BitProcess);
}
```

If the source path isn't passed (like if I execute the application directly), RedGate will use the default location (the executing assembly path).

Once the windows is opened, the user could press the Show (or ShowDialog) button. The application "simply" run these lines of code:

```
//Generates client id and server id
string appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
string controlId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

_service = AppServer.Start(appId, controlId);
_service.FormCompleted += Service_FormCompleted;
_locator = new FormServiceLocator(appId, controlId);
_element = _handle.CreateElement(_locator);
_service.StartRemoteClient();
_service.ShowDialog((long)Handle);
```

When the user will close the window, the callback function will be called:

```
private void Service_FormCompleted(object sender, AppServerEventArgs e) {

    //Check if invoke is required
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        Invoke(new Action<object, AppServerEventArgs>(Service_FormCompleted), sender, e);
        return;
    }

    _element = null;

    MessageBox.Show(this, $"Result: {e.Result} - Data: {e.AdditionalData}");
}
```

### MainApplication.Launcher

This is the project that launch our application with ShadowCopy enabled. I pass as argument the path of the binaries.

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("CefSharp-Remoting", 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);
domain.ExecuteAssembly(executablePath, new[] { $"\"/path:{assemblyPath}\"" });
```

### Why I forked the RedGate.AppHost repository

RedGate.AppHost try to found the Clients application looking into the Assembly location. With ShadowCopy enabled, this is not possible, because the application is copied into a "random" folder, and the Client application is in the source path.

I added the ClientExecutablePath property into the ChildProcessFactory.cs and ProcessStarter.cs, so the ProcessStarter use this folder instead of default folder if this property is setted.

You can see that edits in the follow files:

- https://github.com/rupertsciamenna89/RedGate.AppHost/blob/master/RedGate.AppHost.Server/ChildProcessFactory.cs
- https://github.com/rupertsciamenna89/RedGate.AppHost/blob/master/RedGate.AppHost.Server/ProcessStarter.cs